# Storing models and relationships in a graph database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, orientdb

I have the following models:

```
Person (:age, :gender)
Company (:name, address)
Products (:price, :name)
```

A Person can own several Companies and can also be a customer of several Companies. A Company can manufacture several Products but can also purchase Products manufactured by other Companies.

How can this be represented using OrientDB and Neo4J and how can I query such models in Rails/what would be the best choice in terms of gems?

Example query: find all Products between a specific price range manufactured by Companies owned by Persons who are between 30 and 40 years of age (assuming Person has an attribute :age), who have most Persons between 20 and 30 years of age as customers.

Note: I haven't yet decided whether I'll use OrientDB or Neo4j for the application, or perhaps I will use Neo4j for the chunks of data handled by open sourced parts of my application.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A Person can own several Companies and can also be a customer of
>   several Companies. A Company can manufacture several Products but can
>   also purchase Products manufactured by other Companies.

To model it you should use Labels and Relationships between entities:

In your case it could be like

```
(p:Person)-[:OWNED_BY]->(c:Company),
(p:Person)-[:IS_CUSTOMER]->(c:Company),
(c:Company)-[:MANUFACTURED_BY]->(pr:Product),
(c:Company)-[:USES]->(pr:Product)
```

And you can query it like

```
Match (p:Products) where p.price < 2000 and p.price > 1000 with p
Match (p)<-[MANUFACTURED_BY]-(c:Company)<-[:OWNED_BY]-(owner:Person)
where owner.age < 40 and owner.age > 30 with p, c, owner
Match (c)<-[:IS_CUSTOMER]-(employee:Person) 
where employee.age < 30 and employee.age > 20 
with p, c, count(employee) as midYeareEmployee ...
```

Comment: Cheers Evgen, this is great!

Answer (score 3):

In Orient your model should be like this one:

[image]

To create it here is the commands to run:

```
create class Person extends V
create property Person.age integer
create property Person.gender string

create class Company extends V
create property Company.name string
create property Company.address string

create class Products extends V
create property Products.price integer
create property Products.name string

create class own extends E
create class costumer extends E
create class manufacture extends E
create class purchase extends E
create class manufactured extends E

insert into Person(age,gender) values (20,"M")
insert into Company(name,address) values ("company_01","address_01"),("company_02","address_02"),("company_03","address_03"),("company_04","address_04")
insert into Products(price,name) values (200,"product_01"),(750,"product_02"),(90,"product_03"),(368,"product_04"),(112,"product_05")

create edge own from #12:0 to #13:0
create edge own from #12:0 to #13:1

create edge customer from #13:2 to #12:0
create edge customer from #13:3 to #12:0

create edge manufacture from #13:2 to #14:0
create edge manufacture from #13:2 to #14:1
create edge manufacture from #13:2 to #14:2

create edge purchase from #13:2 to #14:4

create edge manufacture from #13:0 to #14:4
create edge manufacture from #13:0 to #14:0
```